# Determining which points fall within 3D polygon and exporting this subset to flat file

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, polygon, 3d, query-layer

I am working in ArcMap 10 and will have a 3D representation of a zone of transmission.  I would like to determine which GPS points fall within this polygon and then export this subset out to a flat file.  I have visualized info using 3D analyst but have not queried 3D as before in the 2D world.

Comment: What file format is your “3D representation of a zone of transmission” in?